# Append a datetime to a text string written to a file

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am getting the subject and the date sent for every email in a mailbox folder to use in a BI dashboard.

```bsh
$output = $email | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Output $_.Subject + "--" + ($_SentOn).ToShortDateString
}
```

The above code gives me no value in the date segment.

Comment: `$_SentOn` -> `$_.SentOn`

Comment: Didn't get what I expected.   I see+--+

OverloadDefinitions         
-------------------         
string ToShortDateString()

Comment: `ToShortDateString` -> `ToShortDateString()`. The trailing parentheses are required because it's a method, not a property.

Comment: That errors as well.   .SentOn.ToShortDateString() }
+                                                                       ~
An expression was expected after '('.

Comment: I won't be playing Twenty Questions with you. If you need help with an error: update your question with your code and the complete error message.

Comment: When I use { write-output $_.Subject+"--"+$_.SentOn.ToShortDateString() }  errors with the function ToShortDateString() needs a parameter.  I pulled out the "--" and used a , and it shows up as a second column.  Thanks for your help.